# Statute Book vs. Government Gazette

Tags: legal-terms, indonesia

Try to find the translation of Indonesian term "Lembaran Negara" which means 'a piece of paper where all government regulations are promulgated. A regulation is considered valid if it is put on the Lembaran Negara.

Is this concept the same with "statute book" which means ‘the collection, chronologically, of statutes approved by the legislative body of the country forming the legal code’? Is a bill considered as an official regulations only if it has been written in the statute book? Or statute book is merely a compilation of legal code? And what about government gazette? Do those terms share the same concept?

Answer (score 1):

Statute Book has closer meaning to `Lembaran Negara`. There is some confusion when we are speaking about `Lembaran Negara` because in Dutch we called it `Staatsblad` or `Official Gazette` in English. Meanwhile, the term of `Official Gazette` in Indonesia is `Berita Negara` or `De Javasche Courant`.

The concept is not very similar. `Berita Negara` used by the government to announce the regulation that has been approved and also other events such as the establishment of a company, Indonesian citizenship, etc. `Lembaran Negara` used only to announced new regulation.